# Set default color for top

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, top

How do you set the default color for `top`? Right now there is a red that I can barely read. You can toggle from mono to color with <kbd>z</kbd> or set it up more thoroughly with <kbd>Z</kbd>. But none of those settings stick.

How do you set the colors permanently?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use <kbd>W</kbd> (capital w) to save the top configuration after you made your changes.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe add that you have to press "W" in the main view of `top`. Not the view where you change colors.